# Is it a good practice to switch layout managers dynamically as per the requirement?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

In my project, i need to switch between Mig Layout and Card layout on particular menu selection. i just want to know,Is it a good practice to switch between layout managers dynamically as per requirement in application ? Suggestions are most welcome,thank you.

Comment: What is the idea you had in mind, that would make you consider this? Maybe we can offer alternatives.

Comment: Hello Sir,actually mig layout on jdesktoppane was not allowing one jinternalframe to open over another so i switch to card layout for achieving this purpose and kept mig layout as it is for rest of the jframes.

Comment: The description in your comment makes it sound like the code is actually *combining* layouts.  I.E. using two at the same time. That is very common.  In fact, if code adds a `JPanel` to a `JFrame`, and does not *explicitly* set any layouts, it has already happened.  The `JPanel` by default has a `FlowLayout` and the (content pane of the) frame has a `BorderLayout`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching layouts is probably not a good idea. Layout managers use different types of constraints to position your components. Switching managers generally invalidates the constraints. That being said, you may be able to switch specifically from Mig to Card without too much of an issue since Card does not require constraints. Switching back may be quite unpredictable though. Certainly switching to something like GridBagLayout is not advisable.

Comment: Hello Sir,thank you for your valuable suggestion,i tried switching in between mig layout and card layout programmatically and it is working fine,so should i carry on with the same ? thank you.

Comment: Yes. As I said Mig->Card is probably OK. As long as you do not need Card->Mig, you are probably fine.

Comment: Sir,i tried both Mig->Card and Card->Mig,both are working fine when i run my application.

Comment: That probably means that your implementation of Card does not remove the constraints set by the Mig layout. It will also matter whether you kept the original Mig layout or created a new one. The former is more likely to work.

Answer (score 1):

> ..actually mig layout on jdesktoppane was not allowing one jinternalframe to open over another so i switch to card layout for achieving this purpose and kept mig layout as it is for rest of the jframes.

That description makes it sound like the code is actually *combining* layouts.  I.E. using two at the same time. That is very common.

In fact, if code adds a `JPanel` to a `JFrame`, and does not *explicitly* set any layouts, it has already happened.  The `JPanel` by default has a `FlowLayout` and the (content pane of the) frame has a `BorderLayout`..